# Adapt box's height to its flexbox content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox div inside a div box and I'm trying to adapt the box's height according to it's flexbox div content.

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bc0s6fp2/) of what I have till now. As you can see the 2nd box has the text outside of it:

[image]

and I need to have it like this:

[image]

I have tried with several options, like:

```
flex: 1;
flex-direction: column;
flex-basis: auto;
display: inline-flex;
```

but no one works. Some ideas about it?

```css
.Timeline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
}

.event1,
.event2,
.event3 {
  position: relative;
}

.event1Bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.1);
  width: 139px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -70px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.64)
}

.event2Bubble {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.1);
  width: 139px;
  height: 60px;
  left: -105px;
  top: 33px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.64)
}

.event1Bubble:after,
.event1Bubble:before,
.event2Bubble:after,
.event2Bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.event1Bubble:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.66);
  border-width: 12px;
}

.event1Bubble:after {
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 13px;
  border-top-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-width: 12px;
}

.event2Bubble:before {
  bottom: 59px;
  left: 103px;
  border-top-color: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.66);
  border-width: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.event2Bubble:after {
  bottom: 57px;
  left: 103px;
  border-top-color: #F6F6F6;
  border-width: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.eventTime {
  display: flex;
}

.DayDigit {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.Day {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4C4A4A;
}

.MonthYear {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 9px;
}

.eventTitle {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: #a71930;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.time {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}

.eventAuthor {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  top: -8px;
  left: 63px;
}

.event2Author {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 96px;
  left: -32px;
}

.time2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-top: -31px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
}

.now {
  background-color: #004165;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #004165
}

.futureGray {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

.futureOpacity {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.3);
  filter: opacity(.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="Timeline">

  <svg height="5" width="200">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="0" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:5" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

  <div class="event1">

    <div class="event1Bubble">
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">02</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Wednesday
          <div class="MonthYear">february 2016</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="eventTitle">Profile Created</div>
    </div>
    <div class="eventAuthor">by Youri Nelson</div>
    <svg height="20" width="20">
       <circle cx="10" cy="11" r="5" fill="#004165" />
     </svg>
    <div class="time">9 : 27 AM</div>

  </div>

  <svg height="5" width="300">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="300" y2="0" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:5" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

  <div class="event2">

    <div class="event2Bubble">
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">17</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Thursday
          <div class="MonthYear">April 2016</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="eventTitle">Phone Interview today in the afternoon</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event2Author">by Tom Eggleston</div>
    <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="11" r="5" fill="#004165" />
    </svg>
    <div class="time2">1 : 32 PM</div>
  </div>

  <svg height="5" width="50">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:5" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

  <div class="now">
    NOW
  </div>


  <svg height="5" width="150">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="150" y2="0" style="stroke:rgba(162, 164, 163, 0.37);stroke-width:5" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
  <div class="event3 futureGray ">
    <div class="event1Bubble futureOpacity">
      <div class="eventTime">
        <div class="DayDigit">05</div>
        <div class="Day">
          Tuesday
          <div class="MonthYear">May 2016</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="eventTitle">Anticipated Hire</div>
    </div>
    <svg height="20" width="20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="11" r="5" fill="rgba(162, 164, 163, 0.37)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <svg height="5" width="50">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:5" /> 
</svg>
  <svg height="20" width="42">
<line x1="1" y1="0" x2="1" y2="20" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:2" /> 
<circle cx="11" cy="10" r="3" fill="#004165" />  
<circle cx="21" cy="10" r="3" fill="#004165" />  
<circle cx="31" cy="10" r="3" fill="#004165" />    
<line x1="41" y1="0" x2="41" y2="20" style="stroke:#004165;stroke-width:2" /> 
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: you are defining a fixed height (60px) which is the culprit

Answer (score 2):

Your element `.event2Bubble` has a fixed height of 60px.

Change that to `min-height: 60px`, or remove it.

Comment: Have you tried? If I do that, the arrow inside the box will show up, and the person's name still in the same position.

Comment: The problem is you are using fixed positions on the absolutely-positioned elements. You need to use relative units, so the out-of-flow items stay in place when the container changes size.

Comment: You are right, I have some problems with the positions. Will be waiting ... thanks for your help @Michael_B

Comment: Works, but the same happens if the text grows in the first box, like this: => [https://jsfiddle.net/megjwu89/](https://jsfiddle.net/megjwu89/)

Comment: You're going to have problems with this layout because you are using *fixed* (pixel) positions for out-of-flow elements. Any changes to the container size will throw off the positioning, which has been defined for only one size. My suggestion is that you switch to percentage units so everything adjusts smoothly to different container sizes.

Comment: @robe007, sorry, driving now. Can't chat atm.